# Как поменять фон кнопки в android?

Tags: android, xml, android-button

Как поменять фон кнопки в android? Установил android:background="@color/white" и ничего не поменялось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back3"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените атрибут

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

на

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь как это применить к selector?